# why eval function is not recognizing trigonometric when I am using local variable in it?

Tags: python, eval

Here is code

```
equation1 = input("Please Enter an equation")
a = float(input("For a = "))
c = eval(equation1)
```

When I am typing equation with cos, tan, sin and ln functions; i.e : a*cos(a)

I am getting this error:

```
    c = eval(equation1)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cos() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

and inputs like a*cos(90), a**2+cos(90) are working fine, my application is build to be generic. user can give any value is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. if I use `a*cos(a)` as the input string, and assuming i've done `from math import cos` and I've done `a = float(input("For a = "))` then this works

Comment: Works just fine  when not using pycharm, although plesae ensure your code is a [mre] when you ask you future questions - I had to add import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it needs to have `from math import cos`.

When I run with PyCharm, I get the same exception as you.

Then I added `print(equation1)` and found that when I typed `cos(a)`, printed `cos()`.

At first I thought there was something wrong with the `input` function, but I couldn't find the reason.

Then I ran it directly from the terminal command line using `python xx.py` and it worked fine.

So it may be that the `PyCharm` window does not recognize the contents of the parentheses.

Comment: I am using intellij so any fix for that or should I change my IDE?

Comment: @AtifMemon I tried using `VSCode`, and there is no problem. you can use it, but I think you can just use `Terminal` to run the code directly.

Comment: @AtifMemon why don't you just run your code in a terminal? I use PyCHarm, but I use a terminal as well.

Comment: How, exactly, are you running it with PyCharm? The terminal in PyCharm works for me...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga When using the PyCharm `Run` button to run the program, the program executes the `input` input `cos(a)`, and the `print` output `cos()`. The terminal is operating normally.